# Deploy unsafe assembly to production in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions, managed-code

I need to deploy an unsafe UDF assembly to a SQL Server 2005.
I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2008.
I need to know what are the steps that I need to take to allow smooth deployment of unsafe assembly to the client's machine - the client's DBA is a very strict fellow, so I need to satisfy him with a good reasons for fiddling with permissions etc'.

Comment: I found an interesting post (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/26cb4b51-1254-4764-998d-51cbe67af50e) with a suggestion to sign the assembly with an asymmetric key.. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the answer:
[MSDN Article - Creating an Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345106.aspx)
Using asymmetric keys to sign the assembly at the client.